# Cassandra select query giving timeout error with Gocql driver

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am getting timeout error when executing more than 2000 SELECT queries simultaneously. I am using gocql client for Cassandra 3.7 (JAVA version 8).

**"error":"gocql: no response received from cassandra within timeout period"**...

*I am having following table as schema*,

```
CREATE TABLE my_db.my_message (
    id text,
    message_id uuid,
    message text,   
    version text,
    status  tinyint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, message_id)
)

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ON my_db.my_message(status);
```

Below is my query that gives timeout error when executing more than 2000 queries simultaneously.

```
"SELECT * FROM my_db.my_message WHERE id=? AND status = ?"
```

'id' is primary key and 'status' is secondary index in where clause.
'message_id' is also primary key but not used in this select query.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use index on frequently updated or deleted column**

**Remember when not to use an index**

- On high-cardinality columns for a query of a huge volume of records for a small number of results
- In tables that use a counter column.
- On a frequently updated or deleted column
- To look for a row in a large partition unless narrowly queried

I think your column `status` has low cardinality and frequently updated. Since you are narrowing your search by providing partition key `id`, So low cardinality is not a problem for you. **The main problem is you frequently update indexed column status**. Every time you update cassandra store a tombstone.

> Cassandra stores tombstones in the index until the tombstone limit reaches 100K cells. After exceeding the tombstone limit, the query that uses the indexed value will fail.

**So you should filter data by status column value in the application layer.**